# Change color of dropped item and limit item after its dropped in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to change color of the item after it is dropped into cart and then not allow user to drop this item again. Here is code of my accordion:

```
    <div id="products">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>    
        <div id="catalog">
            <h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Lolcat Shirt</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Buckit Shirt</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">Bags</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Zebra Striped</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Black Leather</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>Alligator Leather</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h3><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>iPhone</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>iPod</li>
                    <li class='ui-state-highlight'>iPad</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cart">
        <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <ol>
                <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- End demo --> 

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#catalog").accordion();
        $("#catalog li").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#cart ol").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                    .addClass("cart-item")
                    .appendTo(this);
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            }
        });
        $("#catalog ul").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
            },
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: '.cart-item'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is fiddle, i am able to drag and drop items, however i would like to add some functions like changing color of item in accordion being dropped to droppable area, and also not allow user to drop the same item twice. Any ideas how it can be done? Thanks in advance. Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/t97FE/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=t97FE

Comment: why not a class which has color and also check the text if exist?

Comment: add .cart-item{color:green;font-weight:bolder} to your css for changing color when is droped, to not allow user to drop same item twice, check using jquery.

Comment: @DennySutedja i need to change color in products section not in cart, means after item is dropped to cart, the color of dropped item in catalog should change

Comment: you can have something like this `drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
            $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())
                .addClass("cart-item red")//add class red
                .appendTo(this);
        }` where the class red has style `color:red` in ccss [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/t97FE/252/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: - i use 1.12.1 jQuery-UI and 1.12.4 jQuery

Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var itm = [];
    $("#catalog").accordion();
    $("#catalog li").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $("#cart ol").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                var zz = ui.draggable.text()
                var xyz = itm.includes(zz);

                if(xyz===false){
                    $(this).find(".placeholder").remove();
                    $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text())                    
                    .addClass("cart-item")
                    .appendTo(this);

                    //add to array
                    itm.push(zz);
                    //add style
                    $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('"+zz+"')").addClass('bred');
                }else{
                    alert('Item Already Exist');
                }

        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
        }
    });
    $("#catalog ul").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).remove();
            var zz = ui.draggable.text()
            $('.ui-droppable').find("li.ui-draggable:contains('"+zz+"')").removeClass('bred');

            var indexItm = itm.indexOf(zz);
            if (indexItm > -1) {
                itm.splice(indexItm, 1);
            }
        },
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: '.cart-item'
    });
});    
</script>
```

and CSS:

```
<style>
h1 { padding: .2em; margin: 0; }
#products { float:left; width: 500px; margin-right: 2em; }
#cart { width: 200px; float: left; }
/* style the list to maximize the droppable hitarea */
#cart ol { margin: 0; padding: 1em 0 1em 3em; }

.cart-item{color:green;font-weight:bolder}
.bred{color:red;}
</style>
```

hope this help.